# Too many docker mounts

Tags: docker

I have a web application inside a docker image . The web application is a bit complex, so every time I create a new component inside my app I have to mount another directory.The problem is that I will end up with a command having too many mounts:

```
docker run -v ... -v ... -v ... ... myimage
```

Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea of dockerization that you have immutable containers which you can run everywhere with same result(stateless). If your container has state maybe you have bad architecture solution for your application. Maybe you should separate your application on two. For example, first application will be stateless and another will manage your first application storage. As a variant you can create all your new directory in only one volume:

```
 -v ./app_state:/app_state
```

with the next app_state dir structure

```
app_state
|__ subvolume_1
|__ subvolume_2
|
.
.
.
|__ subvolume_n
```

Comment: your solution turned out to be the best

Answer (score 0):

If thé problèmes is that the command became too long to be typed in a terminal you can use docker compose or a custom script. Then you'll be able to mount as many volumes you want without to rewrite the all stuff anytime you launch a container.

Comment: the volumes are not static, every time I have to add a new mount to the existing mounts.

Comment: Can you give me an example please ??

Comment: I'm not shure it'll fit your need but you can have a look at https://clusterhq.com

Comment: My web application can create projects, and do some tasks according to these projects. Every time I create a new project I must make make a new volume while it is running. So If my application work with, supposedly, 20 projects I must have 20 volumes, and can add new one if I want to.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i suppose your web application store somewhere in a database a list of the projects and the path wher it's stored in the filesystem. If you can modify the source of the web application maybe you can add a procedure that create a file that map project path. And then create a script that start your container and mount each projects in that file (by parsing it with awk). If you can't modify the web app i'm sure you can at least access the projects list in your database and make the parsing process direcly in your container's running script

so your web app create a file like that :

```
Project1 /opt/project1
Project2 /opt/project2
```

and you container's running script look like that :

```
#!/bin/bash

VOLUMES=$(cat projects.txt | awk '{print "-v " $2":/home/"$1}')
COMMAND=$(docker run $VOLUMES myimage)
```

Comment: That can work, although I was looking for a more elegant solution.